# SSRS Report Hyperlink Loses Functionality in .net Application

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have an **SSRS report** that employs **RowGroups** to group data. One of the fields used in the group is a field that stores a URL as text. I've set a Go To URL action on a textbox which enables it to act as a hyperlink that opens up the URL stored as text in a field *(i.e. =Fields!URL.value)*.

The textbox works fine in BIDS and in Report Manager, but when the report is accessed through our custom .asp Reporting Application, the textbox loses this link functionality. It just becomes text. When the mouse is hovered over the textbox, the cursor does not change. I've created another textbox on the report outside the RowGrouping and configured it the same way, and it works fine in the Report Manager and on the Report Application.

Is there any particular configuration that could be restricting a Go to Action property when in a RowGroup on a Reporting Application? Could this be an issue with the report, or an issue on the Reporting App end?

Comment: Cant think of anything. What does the action expression look like?

Comment: The action is Go to URL and the expression specified for the URL is =Fields!URL.Value which references a field from the data set that has a URL stored as text.  It is strange because it works just fine in the Report Manager, but not in the Report Application.  However, when using a textbox outside of the RowGroup, it works fine in both the Report Manager and the Report Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never really found an answer to this problem, but a work around I used was placing a textbox to the right of the grouped textbox, where the link seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ReportExecutionService check to make sure Javascript is true in the device info parameter?

```
<DeviceInfo>
    <JavaScript>True</JavaScript>
</DeviceInfo>
```

But you said it worked if it was in another part of the report?

[link to <DeviceInfo> Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Adam, I will run this by the Report App developer.  Although the expression used for the URL does not use javascript to open a new window, it simply uses =Fields!URL.Value.  Also, another Go To URL textbox outside the group seems to work fine. I am now looking for a way to somehow extricate this textbox from the group and place it outside, yet still referencing the related URL for that particular group instance...